# How can I speed up this code, without numpy etc.?

Tags: python, optimization

I'm new to coding, and I want to become a trainee in one company, I have a problem with my code, could you tell me how can I speed up this part of the code? This section I wrote is very slow, my code should execute in 30 seconds but my execution time, for now, is something about 140 seconds.

I have a list called `bricks_keys` a dictionary with `key = brick name` and `value = bricks amount`.

If we have enough bricks of the type mentioned in the instruction we can build it and we must subtract the bricks amount from the bricks dictionary, else we don't build it and count for missing bricks.

Here's the code:

```py
for i in jerz_buildings:

    temporary_dict = {}
    counter = 0

    for j in instructions[i]:

        if j in brick_keys and instructions[i][j] <= bricks[j]:
            temporary_dict.update({f"{j}":instructions[i][j]})
            counter += 1
            if counter == len(instructions[i]): #  if we can build this
                built += 1
                for i in temporary_dict:
                    bricks[f"{i}"] -= temporary_dict[f"{i}"]
                    bricks_for_first_stage += temporary_dict[f"{i}"]
        else:
            if j in brick_keys:
                temporary_dict.update({f"{j}": instructions[i][j]})
                missing_bricks += abs(bricks.get(j) - instructions[i][j])
                not_built += 1
            else:
                temporary_dict.update({f"{j}": instructions[i][j]})
                missing += abs(bricks.get(j, 0) - instructions[i][j])
                not_built += 1
```

I tried different optimizations, but I could only make it 10 seconds faster.
I don't want to use things like numpy or sth in this case because I think it's not necessary.

Comment: Without seeing all the code, it's nearly impossible to judge anything.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i will put whole code tomorrow i will add also additional comments in script to make it easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so difficult to provide a solution that would work without seeing the entire code. What I would recommend is that you need to:

- Avoid unnecessary dictionary lookups such as bricks[j] and bricks.get(j), and instead assign them to variables outside the loops.
- Convert brick_keys to a set using set(brick_keys) as Sets are faster.
- Combine dictionary updates instead of updating temporary_dict and bricks dictionary separately for each iteration.

Here is optimized code based on these suggestions. Again I am trying to suggest improvement based on the info you provided:

```
brick_keys_set = set(brick_keys)
for i in jerz_buildings:
    temporary_dict = {}
    counter = 0
    
    # Assign to a variable
    bricks_dict = bricks

    for j in instructions[i]:
        brick_value = instructions[i][j]

        # Assign bricks[j] to a variable
        bricks_j = bricks_dict.get(j, 0)

        if j in brick_keys_set and brick_value <= bricks_j:
            temporary_dict[j] = brick_value
            counter += 1
            if counter == len(instructions[i]):
                built += 1
                for brick, amount in temporary_dict.items():
                    bricks_dict[brick] -= amount
                    bricks_for_first_stage += amount
        else:
            temporary_dict[j] = brick_value
            missing_bricks += abs(bricks_j - brick_value)
            not_built += 1

    if len(temporary_dict) > 0:
        missing += sum(abs(bricks_dict.get(brick, 0) - amount) for brick, amount in temporary_dict.items())
        not_built += 1
```

One more thing, these loops can be optimized.